# How does renaming a Bitbucket git repository affect forked repositories?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Let's say I have a Bitbucket git repository under https://bitbucket.org/username/badname. This repository has been forked by several users and they regularly make pull-requests.

I now decide to rename the Bitbucket repository to https://bitbucket.org/username/bettername. Obviously I will need to update my local .git/config so that it points at the new URL.

Now, what happens to all the forks? How will the rename of my repository affect the ability of the contributors to make pull-requests?

Comment: Also, do previous `git remote` URLs get forwarded? For how long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitbucket handles this well. Your contributors will still be able to make pull requests. They will see the new name of your repository.

(source: I just tested this with a small repository)

Comment: I have also done some testing to collect empirical evidence. The Bitbucket infrastructure will handle the renamed repository gracefully and existing forks will point at the new repository name. Users will be able to use the Bitbucket web interface to sync repositories and create pull requests.

Bitbucket does nothing to help contributors that are only working with git and not via the Bitbucket web interface. In particular anyone who forked the original repository will not be notified of the change and the fact that they need to update their local .git/config to point at the new location.

Comment: Correct.

Repositories are linked through their immutable UUIDs (exposed in API responses) and so renaming a repo has no effect and forks.